# How to update simple dialog option in alert dialog box based on data from database dynamically?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In flutter, need to update the view of alertbox options based on data in database. When it has 3 items, it should build 3 simple dialog option in dialog.  Its should get no of widgets and its value from database and then build alert box based on it dynamically.[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information on what you need help specifically?
Do you already have the data that should be displayed retrieved from the database and just need to display it or do you need help retrieving the data?

Comment: yes i have data in database that is to be displayed.  in the picture i just added text as static values (not one from db). it need to be shown accrd. to the data in db. if it has 2 values 2 options, 3 values 3 options.